# How to create and deploy a contract with ether attached?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How to create and deploy a contract with ether attached in web3.js?
In solidity, I know it can be writted like this:

```js
D newD = (new D).value(amount)(arg);
```

But how to write it in web3.js for testing contract.
Thanks sincerely

Comment: I've had trouble with this as well. It seems the `amount: ` is not included in the options for myContract.new(options).

Answer (score 2):

Just attach the attribute of "value: amount" when create contract like this:
.new(
{
from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
value: 5 wei
}